# I don't understand the line below the prompt method of the while loop

Tags: javascript

```
let sum = 0;

while (true) {

  let value = +prompt("Enter a number", '');

  if (!value) break; // (*)

  sum += value;

}
alert( 'Sum: ' + sum );
```

> I don't understand the line below the prompt method. How does it work and what does `if(!value)`
> refers to?

Comment: I added an incorrect tag

Comment: It looks like the tags are fixed now, thanks.

Comment: A JavaScript tutorial or two might be a better starting place than SO. "value" is what's returned from the prompt. "!value" checks of there's no truthy value in it.

Answer (score 1):

The ! used here is the Logical NOT operator. It evaluates any expression or value into a boolean. For truthy values, the ! operator returns false. For falsey values, it returns true. In JavaScript, 0, null, undefined, NaN, '' are all falsey values.

if(!value) would check whether the value is falsey. In case a falsey value is met, the loop will break.